# Overflow scroll in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, create-react-app

This is really weird issue.

I'm working on the react project created with a create-react-app. In html file I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <title>Playground</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</div>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
  </body>

</html>
```

Now inside the body tag you can see div with a lots of lorem ipsum text. I'm inspecting this div inside the browser(Chrome). I'm giving this 3 properties:

```
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
overflow: scroll
```

and surprisingly for me I cannot scroll thru div. Obviously if I test it in another way, ie. create just a html file (old-school way) a paste there the same code, inspect the same div, give it the same properties with the same values it will be scrolling as expected. Hope it is trivial issue.

Comment: Can you provide a working code snippet with your issue, or, at least, your css/js you are working with around this issue?

Comment: But as you can see there it can be no css or js file connected to it and the issue still exists. But it is true that context files can cause that cause when I cut the html file and paste it just without react context everything works fine.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216464/how-to-insert-code-properly-on-stack-overflow   

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support

Comment: Is this `index.html`?

Comment: @sudobangbang yes